# Php and macros(lisp style)?

Tags: php, macros, eval

Hi im learning LISP and well, all day i program php for a living, so i was messing around with php.net and found the eval function... so i started playing around!

I would love to know more about how to use eval to do crazy stuff, i know you can make functions with this and everything... but i wanted to ask why the next code wont work:

```
$var = "echo \"FOZZ\";";
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
    $var  = "eval(\"".$var."\");";
print $var;   
eval($var);
```

Also what other stuff is interesting with eval!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement comes out to 'eval("eval("echo"FOZZ";");")'. Your double quotes are interfering with each other and causing the error.

You might want to try changin the first line to $var = "echo \'FOZZ\';";

Note: Please be careful using eval.

Answer (score 1):

For the common case of web programming Ive developed a library called xilla_tags that makes it easy to write lisp-flavoured PHP code, which can be much more readable that the traditional approach.

For xilla_tags see [xilla tags sample](http://quantblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/xilla_tags-php-library-make-html-with-lispy-php-code/).

Regarding lisp style in PHP, Jacob Hannsen has a great article on his bitchware site for a more general case.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because you need to escape the quotes inside a quoted string.  Since `$var` contains quotes, you need to escape the quotes at each iteration of stuffing it inside another layer of eval.

But regardless, I do not condone using `eval()` excessively like this.  Using it even once should be rare and done only in the most necessary cases.  `eval()` in any programming language is an [accident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) waiting to happen.

Comment: I wouldn't say in _any_ language. But certainly in php.